# Why can't I save directly with User.last.sign_up_completed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote a simple definition

```
  def sign_up_completed!
    self.sign_up_completed_at = Time.now.utc
  end
```

In rails console, I tried to do `User.last.sign_up_completed!`.

```
irb(main):004:0> User.last.sign_up_completed!
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> 2015-05-25 15:37:24 UTC
```

I had to do the following in order to save:

```
> User.last
> u = _
> u.sign_up_completed!
> u.save
```

why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not save when you alter an attribute in that way. Your function would need to be

```
def sign_up_completed!
  self.sign_up_completed_at = Time.now.utc
  self.save!
end
```

Alternatively, you can use `update_attribute` like this, which will save automatically:

```
def sign_up_completed!
  self.update_attribute :sign_up_completed_at, Time.now.utc
end
```

Or don't use a function at all and just call `update_attribute` on the user model, but this may be less readable:

```
user.update_attribute :sign_up_completed_at, Time.now.utc
```